# Custom Attribute of Integer on Custom View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having a few problems creating an integer attribute.
So, as background. I have got a custom canvas view. I have already successfully created a custom string attribute on that. The axml looks like this:

```
<turbineApp.droid.infrastructure.customViews.TurbineMapCanvas
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/VicMapCanvas"
    custom:mapName="VIC"
/>
```

And the attribute comes from **attrs.xml**:

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="CustomCanvasView">
    <attr name="mapName" format="string" />     
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I was hoping to add an integer attribute. So, I added the following as an element in **attrs.xml**:

```
<attr name="originY" format="integer" />
```

But now the project won't build. At all. With a fail message that the Resources class never got built.

I've unblocked myself by just making it a string and parsing the string in the code. But why will an integer not work? Have the good people at Xamarin not implemented that yet?

Thanks

Comment: @jzeferino It now compiles for me too! That is kinda annoying. I had a good 3 hours of cleaning, rebuilding, manually deleting obj and bin folders and even the generated resources class. Every time, build failed. Xamarin has come a long way. But I still encounter these  bumps in the road with the tooling from time to time.